# Active Directory attribute not retrieved in PHP

Tags: php, active-directory

I am trying to retrieve AD attributes for a user in my PHP application. I successfully bind and am able to retrieve attributes. I have a custom attribute called "**Cust1**" which is not retrieved in the LDAP call. Apart from that, all attributes are retrieved.

My Code:

```
$ldap_server_url = "<<server_url>>"; ##GLOBAL CATALOG##
$ldap_bind_dn = '<<bind dn>>';
$ldap_bind_dn_password = '<<bind password>>';

$ldapconn = ldap_connect($ldap_server_url);
$ldap_bind = @ldap_bind($ldapconn, $ldap_bind_dn, $ldap_bind_dn_password);
$attr = array('*');
$test = ldap_search($ldapconn, "dc=mydomain,dc=com", "(samaccountname=mydemouser)", $attr);
$entry = ldap_first_entry($ldapconn, $test);

$attrs = ldap_get_attributes($ldapconn, $entry);
var_dump($attrs);
```

Is there something I need to do so I can retrieve this value?

Comment: does the custom attribute show up when you query ad directly from cmd line ( dsquery ) or similar method?

Comment: no. is this because i am trying to query the Global Catalog in my AD Forest? i have added the attribute accordingly though

Comment: have you made sure the attribute is available in the Global Catalog by ticking the appropriate boxes in Schema Admin?

Comment: i just did that and it worked. Thanks a lot. If you add an answer, I will mark it as the correct one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To ensure that particular attributes of an object in Active Directory are available within the Global Catalog and visible when attempting to display them in, for instance, an ldap search in php they must be modified in the schema.

[image]